# Replace every _ character with upper case letter following _ character

Tags: php, regex, string

How would I go about solving this:

I want to transform strings like this:

```
some_words => someWords
some_more_text => someModeText
```

Hope you get the point, I need to replace every _x with X.

I have something like this now:

```
$string = 'some_words';
$new = preg_replace('/_([a-z])/', strtoupper('$1'), $string);
```

But this does not work. Can I use built in PHP functions inside preg_replace function?

How would I solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_match_callback), like this:

```
$new = preg_replace_callback('/_([a-z])/', function( $match) { 
    return strtoupper( $match[1]);
}, $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you didn't want to use regex, you could do this simply using `explode/implode`

```
$string = 'some_words';
$string_array = explode('_', $string);
for ($i = 1; $i < count($string_array); $i++) {
    $string_array[$i] = ucfirst($string_array[$i]);
}
$string_camel_case = implode('', $string_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the comments in the [man page on `ucwords`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php#92092)

```
$string = 'some_words';
$new = preg_replace('/_(.?)/e',"strtoupper('$1')",$string);
```